# Error building in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. But after updating my Android Studio to the latest version everything works fine, but when I decide to run the app I get this error:

> (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\collinluvpc.gradle\caches\2.14.1\classAnalysis\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified))

I have tried to invalidate cache and restart but nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: my build.gradle

Comment: Please write more specific-descriptive topic regarding the problem

Comment: Once clean gradle from terminal using this command   gradlew .clean

Answer (score 0):

At first **Upgrade SDK Manager .**

> (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\collinluvpc.gradle\caches\2.14.1\classAnalysis\cache.properties (The system cannot find the file specified))

This exception is thrown during a failed attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname.

What is your classpath ??

You can use

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:current_version'`
 & Use this

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:current_version'`

**Then Clean-Rebuild Your Project .**

Comment: Why would compiling an outdated version of Google play services or Gradle Plugin solve the problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 I got this from my old Android book, i just updated my code.

Comment: Again, the problem seems to be with the Gradle cache. I can understand the Gradle Plugin, but not the Google play services

Comment: @cricket_007 I found this helpful last time, using both. This might also help: dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
}

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Settings > Build Tools > Gradle > Configure "Gradle User Home to" -> user/.android/.gradle